# Does Intelligent Blademaster affect Thrown Melee Weapons?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, swordmage

The *Intelligent Blademaster* Feat says that it allows the swordmage to use intelligence for basic attacks with melee weapons.

As it doesn't specify whether the melee weapons have to perform a melee attack for this to apply, can intelligence also be used when throwing melee weapons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, so long as you're attacking with a melee weapon you may apply intelligent blademaster.**

[Intelligent Blademaster](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=613) states:

> Benefit: You can use your Intelligence modifier instead of your Strength modifier when making a basic attack with a melee weapon.

And so the crucial determinator is the "[Weapon Category](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=662)" of the weapon:

> Weapons in all categories are further defined as either melee or ranged and as either one-handed or two-handed.
>
> Melee: A melee weapon is used to attack a target within the weapon’s reach. Unless otherwise noted, a melee weapon has a reach of 1 square. Melee weapons are used with melee powers and with close powers that have the weapon keyword. A melee weapon cannot be used with a ranged power or an area power that has the weapon keyword, unless the weapon has the light thrown or the heavy thrown property or the weapon is thrown as an improvised ranged weapon.

Thus, because the melee category explicitly allows thrown weapons, Intelligent Blademaster allows thrown weapons.

Comment: [Brian](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/760/brian-ballsun-stanton) It does not work with Light Thrown weapons, and your answer does not make it clear.

Comment: @András You're saying it won't work because light thrown weapons use Dexterity?

Comment: @DCShannon, exactly.